# Get post meta after insert post

Tags: post-meta, wp-insert-post

I am trying to get post meta after post is being inserted via code but its not working.

**Post meta not showing:**

```
$id = wp_insert_post( $post_args );
$zip=get_post_meta( $id,'baseSalary',true);
print_r($zip);
```

**Below code is working:**

```
$id = wp_insert_post( $post_args );
    $zip=get_the_title( $id);
    print_r($zip);
```

Comment: How are you setting the `baseSalary` meta to begin with? Can you show the `$post_args` used?

Comment: Right. Show your `$post_args`. If you have used `meta_input` while register post type in `$post_args` then you'll get it.

Answer (score 0):

$id = wp_insert_post( $post_args );

$zip=get_post_meta( $id,'baseSalary',false);

print_r($zip);

write false rather than true if you want to get the array of values.